# angular update property on change of another property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array as shown below

```
var testData = {
    section1: [{
        Number1: 0
    }],
    Total: 0
}
```

In the above array I can have number of ui elements bound to number as textboxes. I want on change of each textbox value to update the "Total" on the testData.

Example:

If i hav e 3 textboxes bound to Number1 with values 10, 20, 30 the total value should be 60 i.e. 10+20+30.

I tried using $scope.$watch, I am not sure how to watch a list array inside an array.

Please help.

Comment: So you can have multiple objects in section1 each bound to its own text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to calculate the total and show the value. The AngularJS 1.x "double binding" will do the rest.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // added more data for demonstration
    $scope.testData = {
    section1: [{
        Number1: 0
        },
        {
        Number1: 0
        },
        {
        Number1: 0
        }],

        Total: 0
 };
    
    $scope.trackTotal = function() {
        var total = 0;

        // I tried using reduce but didn't work, still figuring why
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.testData.section1.length; i++) {
           total += Number($scope.testData.section1[i].Number1);
        }

        // keeping the object property updated
        $scope.testData.Total = total;
        console.log($scope.testData.Total);
        return total;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="data in testData.section1">
        <li>
            Number1[{{$index}}] <input type="text" ng-model="data.Number1">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{trackTotal()}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try using :

```
<input type="text" ng-change="updateTotal ()" />
```

in your controller, define updateTotal to calcul the new total.

The offical documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange